# how to use STS to create a "spring boot + mysql + hibernate" webservice

Tags: spring, spring-boot

i'm a android developer. but now, i need to create a webservice project.
  i try to create a spring project by STS. and i found some demo code from internet. but it doesn't work. when i run the application. console output error log:

- error log:

  ```
   Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'test_spring.customer' doesn't exist
          at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
          at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
          at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
          at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
          at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
          at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
          at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1054)
          at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4237)
          at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4169)
          at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2617)
          at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2778)
          at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2825)
          at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2156)
          at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2459)
          at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2376)
          at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2360)
          at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:187)
          ... 48 more
  ```
- Application.java

  ```
  public class Application {

      public static void main(String[] args) {
      ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(Application.class);

      CustomerRepository repository = context.getBean(CustomerRepository.class);

      // save a couple of customers
      repository.save(new Customer("Jack", "Bauer"));
      repository.save(new Customer("Chloe", "O'Brian"));
      repository.save(new Customer("Kim", "Bauer"));
      repository.save(new Customer("David", "Palmer"));
      repository.save(new Customer("Michelle", "Dessler"));

      // fetch all customers
      Iterable<Customer> customers = repository.findAll();
      System.out.println("Customers found with findAll():");
      System.out.println("-------------------------------");
      for (Customer customer : customers) {
          System.out.println(customer);
      }
      System.out.println();

      // fetch an individual customer by ID
      Customer customer = repository.findOne(1L);
      System.out.println("Customer found with findOne(1L):");
      System.out.println("--------------------------------");
      System.out.println(customer);
      System.out.println();

      // fetch customers by last name
      List<Customer> bauers = repository.findByLastName("Bauer");
      System.out.println("Customer found with findByLastName('Bauer'):");
      System.out.println("--------------------------------------------");
      for (Customer bauer : bauers) {
          System.out.println(bauer);
      }

            context.close();
      }
  }
  ```
- Customer.java

  ```
      @Entity
      public class Customer {

          @Id
          @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
          private long id;
          private String firstName;
          private String lastName;

          protected Customer() {}

          public Customer(String firstName, String lastName) {
              this.firstName = firstName;
              this.lastName = lastName;
          }

          @Override
          public String toString() {
              return String.format(
                      "Customer[id=%d, firstName='%s', lastName='%s']",
                      id, firstName, lastName);
          }

      }
  ```
- CustomerRespository.java

  ```
    public interface CustomerRepository extends CrudRepository<Customer, Long> {

         List<Customer> findByLastName(String lastName);
    }
  ```
- application.properties

  ```
     spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/test_spring
     spring.datasource.username=user
     spring.datasource.password=123456
     spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver


     spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
     spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
     spring.jpa.show-sql=true
  ```
- pom.xml

  ```
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
          <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>mysql</groupId>
          <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
          <version>5.1.27</version>
      </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  ```

=================================

why it doesn't auto create table.

please help me fix it or tell me how to create a webservice project, thank you very much. haha

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you may just need to add the following to `application.properties`:

```
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
```

However, you have also configured it to use `SQLServerDialect`. That should be:

```
org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
```

or

```
org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
```

Comment: I would recommend to use the `MySQL5InnoDBDialect` instead of the `MySQLDialect`.